# How to change the flatfile connection manager "file name" value in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, connection, flat-file

I have  an ssis package...which read data from fixed-column-width text file into DB table.

And I am modifying an existing ssis package. 
I have a flat file source...and flat file cnnection. When I try to edit the flat file connection...using "flat file connection manager editor"..., under "general" part...even if I select different filename..it's not getting reflected.

OR...select the properties window of "Flat File Connection" - once I change connection string and click "save" of visual studio...it rollback

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you don't have access to the package itself? Right clicking on the file icon in the Connection Manager below and selecting 'Rename' and then renaming it right there and then saving the package should work.

Comment: I found out the issue.the issue is...if you goto flatfile connection properties..."Expressions"->Connection string is configured there. I face one issu now...When give a ftp path there..the SSIS gives me error . How to give the file path?

Comment: A FlatFile cannot connect to FTP. You need to use a FTP connection Manager for that.

Answer (score 3):

Pulling a useful comment into an answer...

It's possible that that Connection string (the file path, name) is set from an expression/user or project parameter.

To check, right-click the flat-file connection manager and go to `Properties`, then check `Expressions` to see if the `ConnectionString` is set from a variable such as `@[User::MyFileConnectionString]`

That would cause this behavior of it seemingly "un-doing" after you change it manually.

Comment: That is what's happening to me. I found this connection string being constructed in an expression. The existing expression is @[User::FilePath]+ @[User::FileName] where User::FilePath resolves to a path on the C drive. Need to change this to D. Where do I go to change what User::FilePath points to?